# Proper Usage of PyTorch's non_blocking=True for Data Prefetching

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I am looking into prefetching data into the GPU from the CPU when the model is being trained on the GPU. Overlapping CPU-to-GPU data transfer with GPU model training appears to require both

1. Transferring data to GPU using `data = data.cuda(non_blocking=True)`
2. Pin data to CPU memory using `train_loader = DataLoader(..., pin_memory=True)`

However, I cannot understand how non-blocking transfer is being performed in this [official PyTorch example](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py#L280-L291), specifically this code block:

```py
for i, (images, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # measure data loading time
        data_time.update(time.time() - end)

        if args.gpu is not None:
            images = images.cuda(args.gpu, non_blocking=True)
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            target = target.cuda(args.gpu, non_blocking=True)

        # compute output
        output = model(images)
        loss = criterion(output, target)
```

Won't `images.cuda(non_blocking=True)` and `target.cuda(non_blocking=True)` have to be completed before `output = model(images)` is executed. Since this is a synchronization point, `images` must be first fully transferred to the CUDA device, so the data transfer steps are effectively no longer non-blocking.

Since `output = model(images)` is blocking, `images.cuda()` and `target.cuda()` in the next `i` iteration of the `for` loop will not occur until the model output is computed, meaning no prefetching in the next loop iteration.

If this is correct, what is the correct way to perform data prefetching to the GPU?

Answer (score 10):

I think where you are off is that `output = model(images)` is a synchronization point. It seems the computation is handled by a different part of a GPU. Quote from [official PyTorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#cuda-memory-pinning):

> Also, once you pin a tensor or storage, you can use asynchronous GPU
> copies. Just pass an additional `non_blocking=True` argument to a
> `to()` or a `cuda()` call. **This can be used to overlap data
> transfers with computation**.

Comment: Should  ```non_blocking=True```  be applied to both images and targets? Since images are going to be used in computation, how would that help?

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi Yes for both because torch can pre-fetch the 2nd batch while the first one is doing through its computational steps of foward / backward pass.

Answer (score -5):

To properly implement GPU pre-fetch on PyTorch, you must transform the for-loop into a while-loop.

The DataLoader should be changed into an iterator using the `iter` function, e.g. `iterator = iter(loader)`.

Use `next(iterator)` at each step inside the while-loop to get the next mini-batch.

The end of the DataLoader can be detected by catching the `StopIteration` from the iterator.

Use a flag to end the while-loop when `StopIteration` is raised.